# Ubuntu 19.04 bluetooth not working (OptiPlex 5060)

Tags: bluetooth, 19.04

I am using a Dell OptiPlex 5060 which is supposed to have an inbuilt bluetooth, `Atheros Communications 0cf3:e009`, however Ubuntu 19.04 is unable to detect it, unable the bluetooth settings it states "No Bluetooth Found. Plug in a dongle to use Bluetooth".

Here are some useful outputs:

`lspci -knn | grep Net -A2; lsusb`:

```
Bus 001 Device 004: ID 0bc2:ab26 Seagate RSS LLC Backup Plus Slim Portable Drive 1 TB
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 413c:2106 Dell Computer Corp. Dell QuietKey Keyboard
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 17ef:600e Lenovo 
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
```

`rfkill list; dmesg | grep -i blue` :

```
[ 9303.303950] audit: type=1107 audit(1568626728.176:55): pid=1016 uid=103 auid=4294967295 ses=4294967295 msg='apparmor="DENIED" operation="dbus_method_call"  bus="system" path="/" interface="org.freedesktop.DBus.ObjectManager" member="GetManagedObjects" mask="send" name="org.bluez" pid=16976 label="snap.mailspring.mailspring"
[ 9365.700889] audit: type=1107 audit(1568626790.576:57): pid=1016 uid=103 auid=4294967295 ses=4294967295 msg='apparmor="DENIED" operation="dbus_method_call"  bus="system" path="/" interface="org.freedesktop.DBus.ObjectManager" member="GetManagedObjects" mask="send" name="org.bluez" pid=17394 label="snap.whatsdesk.whatsdesk"
[ 9780.379121] audit: type=1107 audit(1568627205.252:63): pid=1016 uid=103 auid=4294967295 ses=4294967295 msg='apparmor="DENIED" operation="dbus_method_call"  bus="system" path="/" interface="org.freedesktop.DBus.ObjectManager" member="GetManagedObjects" mask="send" name="org.bluez" pid=18250 label="snap.whatsdesk.whatsdesk"
[ 9787.980691] audit: type=1107 audit(1568627212.856:64): pid=1016 uid=103 auid=4294967295 ses=4294967295 msg='apparmor="DENIED" operation="dbus_method_call"  bus="system" path="/" interface="org.freedesktop.DBus.ObjectManager" member="GetManagedObjects" mask="send" name="org.bluez" pid=18406 label="snap.whatsdesk.whatsdesk"
[ 9857.254783] audit: type=1107 audit(1568627282.128:65): pid=1016 uid=103 auid=4294967295 ses=4294967295 msg='apparmor="DENIED" operation="dbus_method_call"  bus="system" path="/" interface="org.freedesktop.DBus.ObjectManager" member="GetManagedObjects" mask="send" name="org.bluez" pid=18617 label="snap.whatsdesk.whatsdesk"
```

`lspci -nnk | grep -iA3 net`

```
00:1f.6 Ethernet controller [0200]: Intel Corporation Ethernet Connection (7) I219-V [8086:15bc] (rev 10)
    Subsystem: Dell Ethernet Connection (7) I219-V [1028:085b]
    Kernel driver in use: e1000e
    Kernel modules: e1000e
01:00.0 VGA compatible controller [0300]: NVIDIA Corporation GK208B [GeForce GT 730] [10de:1287] (rev a1)
```

Comment: Does it even find the wifi adapter?  `lspci -nnk | grep -iA3 net`

Comment: I don't think it does, I have edited my question to include the output.